# I am trying to add a section to my wordpress child theme on the customize section, for some reason it doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I got this child theme I made based on twentythirteen and I am trying to add a section.

it always comes up with this error:

Fatal error: Class 'WP_Cutsomize_Colour_Control' not found in /home3/ab78267/public_html/TalkAboutIt/wp-content/themes/Talk_About_It/functions.php on line 15

the following is my php cod ein the functions.php file:

```
function TAB_customizer_register($wp_customize){    

$wp_customize->add_panel('header_colour', array(

'title' => __('Header background colour'),
'description' => 'If you dont want a header image, why not set a background color for it instead?'));

$wp_customize->add_section('header_color', 
array('title' => __('Header Colour','(UOS)Talk AboutIt'),
'description' => 'If you dont want a header image, why not set a background color for it instead?'
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('header_background_color', 
array(
'default' => '#FF9400'
));

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Cutsomize_Colour_Control($wp_customize,

'header_background_color', array(
'label' => __('Edit the colour of the header background',
'(UOS)Talk AboutIt'),
'section' => 'header_color',
'settings' => 'header_background_color')
)); 
}    

add_action('customize_register','TAB_customizer_register');
```

I have also checked the code myself and I have also checked line 15 and there doesn't seem to have a problem with it based on the codex and a tutorial I came across on youtube.

Comment: by the way, I also tried adding a panel and it still didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure without seeing the rest of the code, but is it because the function has a typo in it? You've written "WP_Cutsomize_Colour_Control" instead of "WP_Cu**st**omize_Colour_Control".

Comment: Just fixed the spelling mistake and still doesnt work. And as for the code thats all there is to it

Comment: If it's the same error, then there's a problem in the class definition. You'll have to look at the page you defined the class named "WP_Customize_Colour_Control" and see why it can't find it on the functions.php page. It could be some incorrect includes/requires, or it could be another typo (like Colour/Color?), or something else entirely. The error you're getting is pointing you in the right direction.